# How can i sum the content of a django model

Tags: python, django, sum, calculation

I have this model:

```
class Transfer(models.Model):
        transfer_code = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
        sender_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
        amount = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        recipient_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
        time_sent = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
        received = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        time_received = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.transfer_code
```

This is my view where i want to calculate the total amount in the table:

```
def listtransfersall(request):
    title = 'ALL TRANSFERS'
    queryset = Transfer.objects.all()
    for instance in queryset:
        total = 0
        total += instance.amount
        print total

    context = {
    "title": title,
    "queryset": queryset,
    "total": total,
    }
    return render(request, "listtransfersall.html",context)
```

This prints the amount in the table individually.
How can i get the total and assign it to the total variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your posted code, you set `total = 0` each time through the loop

```
for instance in queryset:
    total = 0
    total += instance.amount
    print total
```

Move that line outside of the loop and this will work the way you intended.

Slightly better would be to get a `values_list` and sum that:

```
amounts = Transfer.objects.values_list('amount', flat=True)
total = sum(amounts)
```

Better still would be to let the database do the work and use the Sum aggregation:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
total = Transfer.objects.aggregate(Sum("amount"))
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/) for more information on aggregations

Answer (score 3):

You can use [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/) for that. In your case, try this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

queryset = Transfer.objects.annotate(total_amount=Sum('amount'))
```

And then use in your template:

```
queryset.total_amount
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your question completely but I think that your problem is that you are declaring `total = 0` inside your loop. So it will always be 0 before you add the value of `instance.amount` on every iteration.

You have to declare `total = 0` before you enter your loop, like this

```
total = 0
for instance in queryset:
    total += instance.amount
print total
```

That code will add `instance.amount` to the `total` variable and the print the total value.